# Multiple choices checkboxes sql design

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I would like to know what would be the best way of storing multiple check-boxes values for easy search.

Is there any advantage if for a skills table (football, swimming, dancing ....) I assign unique id or should I use a unique string - the exact word to be stored in the database?

If the answer is "numbers" and the total available options are more than "10" should I start increment the id from ten  so I can avoid finding 12, 2, 22 for %2% in case storing is made like 14,23,34 / football,swimming,dancing in the user table.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking or what the problem is.  I assume you're talking about mapping "skills" to "people" or something of that nature?  In general I imagine there would be a `Skills` table and a `People` table, and a `PersonSkills` table connecting the two in a many-to-many relationship.  What more is there, and what are you trying to avoid?

Comment: Yes. There is a users table and one skills table and I need to asign all skiils available for each user.
I am used to storing string values separated by commas but I see other websites that assign number value to their chioices and that just makes me wonder if there's something I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 3 tables:

1. `Person` table. This contains single-valued attributed such as name, birthday, etc.
2. `Skills` table. This contains the name of each skill.
3. `PersonSkills` table. This is a relation table that contains the many-to-many relationship between the first two tables. It has two columns: `Person_id` and `Skill_id`, which are foreign keys into the first two tables.

To get all the skills, you join the tables:

```
SELECT person_name, GROUP_CONCAT(skill_name) skills
FROM Person p
LEFT JOIN PersonSkills ps ON p.person_id = ps.person_id
JOIN Skills s ON s.skill_id = ps.skill_id
```

To get all the people with a particular skill:

```
SELECT person_name
FROM Person p
JOIN PersonSkills ps ON p.person_id = ps.person_id
JOIN Skills s ON s.skill_id = ps.skill_id
WHERE skill_name = "swimming"
```

Comment: There are big chances that I will search for more than 1 multiple choice table.
Eye color, voice training, musical instruments.
Would a query where I like to find all people that studied piano and dancing with red hair be a mess or would be straigt forward?

Comment: It's a little complicated, especially since you seem to be a SQL newbie. But you should be able to find SO questions that show how to do it.

Comment: Is this OK?

SELECT u.id
FROM  `users` u

JOIN  `skills_users` su ON u.id = su.user
JOIN  `skills` s ON s.id = su.skill

JOIN  `instruments_users` iu ON u.id = iu.user
JOIN  `instruments` i ON i.id = iu.instrument


WHERE s.name =  'handball' AND i.name = 'flaut'

Is it ok to use as many === JOIN  `instruments_users` iu ON u.id = iu.user
JOIN  `instruments` i ON i.id = iu.instrument === as I need?

Or shall i stick to my old way: SELECT * FROM `users WHERE instruments LIKE '%flaut%' AND `skills` LIKE 'handball'  ?

Comment: Why are yo using jsfiddle for SQL, instead of sqlfiddle?

Comment: If you need help with this, you probably should ask a new question.

Comment: You can join with the same tables multiple times. You need to give them different aliases.

Comment: I think you need to hit the books/websites and learn SQL. I'm not going to try to teach you all this stuff here.

Comment: It's not about getting deeper into it. Just wanted to know if your example is practical before applying it considering all the search criteria I am using.
Thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45512/discussion-between-valid-and-barmar)

Comment: Sorry, not going to get drawn into a long discussion of this.

Comment: Not my intention either. Just clicked on the SO chat suggestion out of curiosity.
Take care!